# Debian how to install downloaded program

Tags: linux, debian, software-installation

I just downloaded https://fah.stanford.edu/file-releases/public/release/fahviewer/debian-testing-64bit/v7.4/fahviewer_7.4.4_amd64.deb . How do I install it? I am used to Windows programs installs where you open a .exe, simple and clean.

I see these files:

```
data.tar.gz
control.tar.gz
debian-binary
```

Each of these files have more files within them.

Answer (score 1):

from a terminal:

```
dpkg -i fahviewer_7.7.4_amd64.deb
```

dpkg is the Debian package manager, and -i tells it to install. You may need root privileges to install, in which case:

```
sudo dpkg -i fahviewer_7.7.4_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Both of those give me: dpkg: error processing archive fahviewer_7.7.4_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fahviewer_7.7.4_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

When you use apt to install a package, internally it uses dpkg. When you install a package using apt it first creates a list of all the dependencies and downloads it from the repository.

Once the download is finished it calls dpkg to install all those files, satisfying all the dependencies.

So if you have a .deb file:

You can install it using  
  **sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file** 
 followed by sudo apt-get install -f.
You can install it using apt-get install package_name. But first move your deb file to /var/cache/apt/archives/ directory. After executing this command, it will automatically download its dependencies.

(it will work if the .deb package is present in the apt package list)

Install gdebi and open your .deb file using it (Right-click -> Open with). It will install your .deb package with all its dependencies.